# Problems with strings in PHP (not adding two strings together properly)

Tags: php

if we say:

```
$termstringDomain1 = "something";
$url = "somethingelse";
$url = 'http://' . $termstringDomain1 . '/' . $url;
```

the result if gives me is: `http:///somethingelse` instead of `http://something/somethingelse`

so basically it is ignoring `$termstringDomain1`
Any idea why?

Comment: This runs fine, your problem exists elsewhere in some code that you haven't pasted.

Comment: but how would it be somewhere else, all what I am doing is that above then (echo $url)

Comment: is that really your $termstringDomain1? maybe your actual variable value is borked

Comment: when I echo $termstringDomain1, it prints (something) on the screen so it is working ...

Comment: @unknown: Your problem is elsewhere. I just copied/pasted your code and could not repro the problem. Why type of server are you on? Which version of PHP?

Comment: @unknown: Check the last point in my answer for a potential solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce this issue:

```
$foo = "foo";
$bar = "bar";
$bar = "sayFoo: " . $foo . ", sayBar: " . $bar;
print $bar; // 'sayFoo: foo, sayBar: bar'
```

Your problem is likely elsewhere. If I copy/paste what you provided, I get the following:

> `http://something/somethingelse`

**Check your variable casing.** `$domain1` is not the same as `$Domain1`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try putting `echo` infront of all the declarations, to try to track the problem down?

```
echo $termstringDomain1 = "something";
echo $url = "somethingelse";
echo $url = 'http://' . $termstringDomain1 . '/' . $url;
```